# Avoiding duplicate records in Solr server

Tags: solr

In my solr admin i am quering like this -

http:// :8080/solr/realestatecategory/select?q=*%3A*&fl=propcategory&wt=json&indent=true

it returns me records like

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":4},
  "response":{"numFound":4,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "propcategory":"Residential Property"},
      {
        "propcategory":"Residential Property"},
      {
        "propcategory":"Commercial Property"},
      {
        "propcategory":"Invest"}]
  }}
```

i want to avoid duplicate records like "Residential Property". how to do that ?

answer the question quickly as i badly need help.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use grouping.

Use `group=true` along with `group.field=propcategory`.

For details have a look [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a unique list of the Records you can check [Solr faceting](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrFacetingOverview) as well.
It will give a list of Items with the Count.